# How to build a review step in a multi step form?

Tags: html, jquery, forms, drupal

I'm currently trying to build a custom multi-step form for a space reservation system in Drupal 9. One of the tasks that is hanging me up is showing a review of all the fields as the last step. I've tried to bind values mentioned [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/how-to-best-show-form-data-for-review-before-submit-js), but must be doing something wrong. Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks!

My `.html.twig` looks like:

```
<form data-multi-step>
   <div class="card active" data-step>
        <div class="dropdown-container">
            <div class="dropdown reserve--type">
                <input type="radio" name="reserveType" value="class" checked="checked" id="type-class" data-bind="type">
                <label for="type-class">class</label>

                <input type="radio" name="reserveType" value="cultural activity" id="type-cultural" data-bind="type">
                <label for="type-cultural">cultural activity</label>

                <input type="radio" name="reserveType" value="conversation group/tutoring" id="type-conversation" data-bind="type">
                <label for="type-conversation">conversation group/tutoring</label>

                <input type="radio" name="reserveType" value="faculty workshop" id="type-faculty" data-bind="type">
                <label for="type-faculty">faculty workshop</label>

                <input type="radio" name="reserveType" value="other" id="type-other" data-bind="type">
                <label for="type-other">other</label>
            </div>

        {% if space.field_occupancy.value is not empty %}
            <div class="dropdown reserve--occupancy">
                <input type="radio" name="reserveOccupancy" value="1" checked="checked" id="occ-1" data-bind="occupancy">

                    <label for="occ-1">1</label>
                    {% for i in range(2, space.field_occupancy.value|number_format) %}
                        <input type="radio" name="reserveOccupancy" value="{{ i }}" id="occ-{{ i }}" data-bind="occupancy">
                        <label for="occ-{{ i }}">{{ i }}</label>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="button button--next" data-next>Next</button>
    </div>

    <div class="card--reserve" data-step>
        ... (similar to step 1)
    </div>


    <div class="card--reserve review" data-step>
        <div data-update="type"></div>
        <div data-update="occupancy"></div>

        <button type="button" class="button button--back" data-previous>Back</button>
        <button type="button" class="button button--submit" data-submit>Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```